Is there a Chrome Devtools Protocol API to list off all Runtime.ScriptIds?
I'm trying to write a script that will dump all instances of a specific function signature in node.js's internal modules. Specifically, I'm trying to dump the locations of the internalBinding function call.
Basically, I'm try to replicate devtools > ctrl+shift+f > "internalBinding" from an automation.
I know that you get script sources using Debugger.getScriptSource(), but it requires a Runtime.ScriptId.
Is there a CDP API for getting all script ids?
